# Sahrepoint 2013 REST - can't pull names in field "AssignedTo"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

I'm using a ShPG workflow in order to pull out the names of people assigned to open issues in an OOTB issues list. I use the CALL action with "this" as follows:

http://site.subsite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Issues')/Items?$select=AssignedTo

But it does not work and if I enter it in the browser it ends in a http400 error message. However, if i.e. I would use

http://site.subsite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Issues')/Items?$select=Title,Status

it works fine and delivers the requested results when entered into the browser.

There are 4 entries in the list, each of them has all fields correctly filled.

Is there any miraculous with the AssignedTo field? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can not get directly data from user field you have to expand user field so your query look like below

```
http://site.subsite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Issues')/Items?$select=Title,Status,AssignedTo,AssignedTo/Title,AssignedTo/Id&$expand=AssignedTo
```

More detail you can refer this [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31210.sharepoint-2013-get-user-details-from-person-or-group-field-using-rest-api.aspx)